# Is Apache ignite supports latest spring boot version 3.x?

Tags: ignite

While migrating spring boot ignite project from 2.7 to 3.x facing bean creation exception related to Apache ignite related dependencies, are Apache ignite supports latest spring boot version?

Tried migrating with latest available gradle dependencies of Apache ignite, no luck. Still same issue exists. Which is not able to create bean for org.apache.ignite.Ignite. While seeing the source code of Apache ignite libraries still it's refering some javax. Packages. Which is completely removed in spring boot 3.x version. Any help from ignite community?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use Ignite in SpringBoot applications, but the autoconfigurer does not currently work with SpringBoot 3.x. There is a ticket/PR so hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please notify here once the support ticket/PR is fixed. So that we can start our migration activity.

Comment: If you need notifications/support, there are commercial options available. I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the right place for that.